# Defining text selection highlight with CSS

Tags: css

I'm having problems designing a CSS for a website I'm making. It's similar to the one shown in this pic:
  [image: this pic].

How can I make it so that when a user selects and blocks the text, the areas on its right and left don't get selected as well? In my case, I've tried wrapping the tag-containing text (and `<article>` tag) inside a `<div>` but I don't see any change.

Comment: This question belongs to stackoverflow

Comment: mgunadi-  Welcome to GD.  This question really isn't about design, more about browser behavior.  As Lollero said, this will probably have better luck on SO.  Furthermore, your question will likely need to be improved as there is no way to tell you what is going wrong based on an image alone.

Comment: On the other hand: this is about an issue that makes one's design fugly *and* that might be salvageable through CSS tweaking (not strictly off-topic as per FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old, but I thought I'd chime in just in case my solution might help anyone the future.

I had the same issue occurring where the text selection was including the padding within a `div` element. I tried @Joseph Marikle's solution; however, I had other elements being floated that were problematic with the float solution and using absolute positioning was not an option.

I then tried looking for ways to remove the elements (`p` elements in my case) from the page flow. I landed on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917168/what-are-the-css-properties-that-get-elements-out-of-the-normal-flow) and decided to try **relative positioning** on my `p` elements and it seemed to produce the desired effect.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/doubleswirve/pen/ItbcL) demonstrating the results. The second `p` element has relative positioning applied to it and the text selection is constrained.

Answer (score 1):

mgunadi and welcome to SO

What's happening here is you have a centering method that leaves a margin.  when you highlight the text in your browser, it also selects the margin.  this can be fixed to some degree by changing the way you center your content.  For instance, if you use a `position:absolute` solution, this margin is not needed and is not selected on highlight. (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FX45g/).  Unfortunately, if this is not an option and you must use a margin to center the content, then this is a browser issue and depends entirely on how a particular browser handles it.

to center content with positioning the content must be of a fixed width (for this example 300px).  then you can apply the following rule:

```
.centered
{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

### EDIT

Found another way. :P a wrapper! (with the help of a float)

http://jsfiddle.net/hSpBw/

```
.wrapper{margin:0 auto; width:300px;}
.wrapper>div {float:left;}
```

Comment: This highlights exactly the same for both examples for me in FF6, and IE8... Aha! But not in Chrome! I'd +1 but absolute positioning is *really* the only fix?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I suspected as much.  Thankfully, it renders *correctly* in FF.  This is (as far as I know) exclusively a Chrome issue. :P  It may be present in other browsers but I've only ever seen it in Chrome.

Comment: @WesleyMurch as far as I know. :(  I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Yep. +1. Since it's a *browser* issue with *text selection*, I'd say it's not too important. If we can fix it - great. If not - no big deal unless it's actually causing unexpected behavior, like copying white space (doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: @WesleyMurch I found another way that doesn't use position:absolute :P

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not provide this feature. It's a function of the browser itself.

Comment: css *can* accommodate for this.  All that's happening is the margin is being highlighted.