# What are the CSS properties that get elements out of the normal flow?

Tags: html, css, dom, position

What are the CSS properties that get elements out of the normal flow?
Such properties would be float, position:absolute etc.

This question relates to all the possible alterations of the normal flow.

Comment: `display` is another one. Can I ask what the underlying problem is? It is possible that there are other attributes which don't nominally alter the flow, but in certain cases they do, like oversized margins.

Comment: Define 'normal flow'? @biziclop, `display` doesn't take documents out of the flow, it merely changes the defaults (though I'm confused by use of the word 'normal' in the question. And, also, the *point* of the question...).

Comment: @DavidThomas `display:none` definitely takes the element out of the flow, whatever the flow is.

Comment: @David Thomas, for example, div's position one after another when they are not manipulated, but when using float they overlap each other.

Comment: @David Thomas: [Normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow)

Comment: Ah, true; I hadn't considered that one (I was stuck with `display: inline` (or `block`, `inline-block`...). My bad =/ Boltclock, yeah...I was more curious as to the OP's understanding of, and meaning by, the phrase; 'normal' is, after all, a commonly-used phrase, despite the technical specification of such by the W3C.

Comment: [Everything other than block or inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow).

Comment: @biziclop: Consider that `display: none` doesn't generate a box for an element at all, so there won't be anything to remove from normal flow in the first place. The other values for `display` do not alter the normal flow.

Comment: @BoltClock Except display: table-*

Comment: oh yea, table also forces div's around

Comment: @DanDascalescu I find the answer given here to be complete rather than the ones from that post.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Only the following properties affects the normal flow of any given element:

- `float: right|left`
- `position: absolute|fixed`

Just for completeness:

- `display: none` removes the element from the flow (strictly speaking the element will not have a flow order)
- `position: relative` does not change the flow order of the element, but changes its position relative to the normal flow position.
- `visibility: hidden` will maintain the element on the flow but will not render it to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ultimate property that literally removes an element from the stream:

```
display: contents;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

It helps a lot when you need to wrap a tr in a div, inside tbody/thead - in case use draggable functionality or something