# Why are both divs the same color? Only 1 is defined as green

Tags: css, html, background

I have two separate divs, why is the background color the same lime color for both? I want the first div white. 
Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="head1">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Link one</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Link two</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Link three</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Link four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="title1">
     <h1>some title</h1>
</div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
 #head1 {
 }
 #title1 {
     height:100px;
     background-color:lime;
 }
 ul {
     float:left;
     width:100%;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     border-bottom:2px aqua dashed;
 }
 li {
     display:inline;
 }
 a.menu {
     float:left;
     width:6em;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:#666666;
     padding:0.2em 0.6em;
     border-right:1px solid white;
 }
 a.menu:hover {
     background-color:#ff3300;
 }
 h1 {
     font-family: Gautami;
     font-size:300%;
     color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you float the list, the #title div essentially appears as if it's behind it. To correct this, add `overflow:auto` to your `#head1` element

```
#head1 {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2JKDF/1)**

Answer (score 2):

It's actually white. You just can't see it.

Because the `ul` (and other elements) are floated left, those elemente are taken out of the DOM's normal flow. What this basically means is that the parent div, `#head1` no longer "sees" the `ul`. Because of this, the height of the div becomes 0px tall.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/w858z/

As you can see, `#head1` has a red border, but the height is 0px. If we remove the floats, the ul is now in the normal flow.

Here's an updated fiddle with the `floats` removed: http://jsfiddle.net/48Ahm/

The fix for this is to use either a `clearfix` or simply `overflow:auto`.

overflow example: http://jsfiddle.net/w858z/1/
clearfix example: http://jsfiddle.net/w858z/2/

Here's a stackoverflow discussing additional css properties that will result in an element being taken out of dom flow: [What are the CSS properties that get elements out of the normal flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917168/what-are-the-css-properties-that-get-elements-out-of-the-normal-flow)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the second div `clear: both;`
I made a jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/5gwZ6/