# Not-normal HTML Flows

Tags: html, css

*Normal* HTML flow is that inline elements stack next to each other (left-to-right or right-to-left depending on culture) and block elements do not, they claim an entire line for themselves.

If an element has an absolute position or is floated then it will be removed from the flow it's declared in.

So...

*Are there three kinds of flow?*

1. Normal
2. Absolute
3. Float

*Is this the terminology you'd use to talk about them?*

**NB**:  I'm not asking *how* to remove an element from normal flow.  I'm asking *what flows are there?* and *what should I call them?*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the CSS properties that get elements out of the normal flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917168/what-are-the-css-properties-that-get-elements-out-of-the-normal-flow)

Comment: Thanks @sol , I'm not asking how to remove and element from normal flow though.  I'm wondering hot many types of HTML flow there are and what I whould refer to them as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the W3 [Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/) in Section 9: [Visual formatting model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html).

This describes [Normal Flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#normal-flow), [Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats) and [Absolute Positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#absolute-positioning).  It also contains a [Comparison of normal flow, floats, and absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#comparison).

Given that these are all discussed together, I think that the confision was that there are different types of flows, but only *normal flow* actually contains the word *flow*.

Therefore, the three types of <s>flow</s> [positioning schemes](http://positioning%20scheme%20(normal%20flow,%20float,%20and%20absolute%20positioning).) as per CSS 2.2 are:

1. Normal Flow
2. Floats
3. Absolute Positioning

They are refered to using these terms.

> **NB:** These are **not** referred to as *flows*, they are refered to a *positioning schemes*.